# RavenDb - What's faster?

Tags: ravendb

I need to do a query in RavenDb and perform a get on a document by Id and a secondary parameter.

To be more precise, I'd like to load a document by document Id and by ApiKey.  If the ApiKey of the given document does not match I want a null back.

My question is, is it faster to do a Query with Id and ApiKey comparison, or is it faster to do a Load by Id and throw away the document in code if the ApiKey does not match.  My documents are probably 20k in size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a load by id, then compare.